# find the value of $\sqrt {(98 \times 100+2)(100\times102+2)+(100\times2)^2}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

From: $2015$ Singapore Mathematical Olympiad Secondary 2 (Grade 8) Question 21 Round 1 on 3rd June.

> Find the value of $\sqrt {(98 \times 100+2)(100\times102+2)+(100\times2)^2}$ (No use of calculators)

My attempt:Special cases formula -> $x^2=(x+1)(x-1)+1$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\sqrt {(98 \times 100+2)(100\times102+2)+(100\times2)^2}&=\sqrt {(99^2-1)(101^2-1)+(100\times 2)^2}\\
\end{align}

Now take $y$=100

\begin{align}
\sqrt {(99^2-1)(101^2-1)+(100\times 2)^2}&=\sqrt {[(y-1)^2-1][(y+1)^2-1]+(2y)^2}\\
&= \sqrt {[y^2-2(y)(1)+1-1][y^2+2(y)(1)+1-1]+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {(y^2-2y)(y^2+2y)+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {y^4-4y^2+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {y^4}\\
&= y^2
\end{align}

$100^2=10000$

therefore $\sqrt {(98 \times 100+2)(100\times102+2)+(100\times2)^2}=10000$

But using the calculator,the answer is 10002.Where did I go wrong,and is there a simpler way to do this other than using long multiplication?

EDITED ANSWER(Error found by @Mathlove):

\begin{align}
\sqrt {(98 \times 100+2)(100\times102+2)+(100\times2)^2}&=\sqrt {(99^2+1)(101^2+1)+(100\times 2)^2}\\
\end{align}

Now take $y$=100

\begin{align}
\sqrt {(99^2+1)(101^2+1)+(100\times 2)^2}&=\sqrt {[(y-1)^2+1][(y+1)^2+1]+(2y)^2}\\
&= \sqrt {[y^2-2(y)(1)+1+1][y^2+2(y)(1)+1+1]+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {(y^2-2y+2)(y^2+2y+2)+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {(y^4-4y^2)+2(y^2+2y+2)-4y-2y^2+4y^2+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {y^4-4y^2+2y^2+4y+4-4y-2y^2+4y^2+4y^2}\\
&= \sqrt {y^4+4y^2+4}\\
&= \sqrt {(y^2+2)^2}
&= y^2+2
\end{align}

$100^2+2=10002$

therefore $\sqrt {(98 \times 100+2)(100\times102+2)+(100\times2)^2}=10002$

Comment: $99^2+1,101^2+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$98\times 100+2\not =99^2-1$$
and that 
$$100\times 102+2\not=101^2-1.$$

We have
$$98\times 100+2=(99-1)(99+1)+2=99^2-1+2=99^2+1$$
and
$$100\times 102+2=(101-1)(101+1)+2=101^2-1+2=101^2+1.$$

Comment: I see,a careless mistake on my end to forgot to include "+2"

Answer (score 1):

$((100-2)100+2)((100+2)100+2)=(100^2-2\times100+2)(100^2+2\times 100+2)=(100^2+2)^2-(2\times 100)^2$

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like you have done, but just put $x=100$ straight away since that is the central number. You can always do the $x^2-1$ simplification afterwards, if it helps, but I would get rid of the big numbers as quickly as possible.

Then $$\left(x(x+2)+2\right)\left(x(x-2)+2\right)+4x^2=x^2(x^2-4)+2x(x+2)+2x(x-2)+4+4x^2=$$$$=x^4-4x^2+2x^2+4x+2x^2-4x+4+4x^2=x^4+4x^2+4$$

So I would work on the part underneath the square root, but I wouldn't write the square root every time.

I find this kind of approach less prone to errors, and more easy to check under test conditions.